# Add values to Hashtable irrespective of index value

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I am retrieving data in a list from database and want to store two of its column in a hash table. But I am able to insert only one row in the hash table where index is 0. Is there a way to insert to hash table without taking index into consideration? I am using the below approach right now. Any suggestions?

```
foreach (StoreInfo store_info_id in StoreList)
            {

                Hashtable hashTable = new Hash table();
                hashTable.Add(StoreList[0].store_info_id, StoreList[0].RetailControlNumber);
            }
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever be using `HashTable`.  You should be using a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Servy  I am not expecting many entries in this table may be 3-4 everytime so hashtable would have been a good option I thought. But I am open to suggestions with doing this using dictionary.

Comment: Your foreach is totally off. The iterator value, store_info_id, is never used.

Comment: @Programmermid The number of values you have in the collection is irrelevant to my point.  You should literally **never** use `HashTable`.  If you want to use a hash based lookup the appropriate type to use is `Dictionary`.  `HashTable` is obsolete.

Comment: Voting to close because of bad non-compiling pseudo code. It's not even clear what you want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points:

1. `Hashtable` is just `Dictionary<object, object>`, before it was possible to have type arguments. So, today there's no longer any good reason to ever use `Hashtable`, except for if you're interfacing with legacy code that was written back when `Hashtable` was the only option.
2. If you want to put *two* columns into the same entry in the dictionary, the proper way to do that is to create a type to represent a record in the dictionary:

   ```
   public class StoreRecord
   {
       public int StoreInfoID;
       public string Column1;
       public string Column2;
   }
   ```

   Then, use a `Dictionary<int, StoreRecord>`:

   ```
   var records = new Dictionary<int, StoreRecord>();

   foreach (var storeDatabaseRow in storeList)
   {
       var record = new StoreRecord();

       record.StoreInfoID = storeDatabaseRow.store_info_id;
       record.Column1 = storeDatabaseRow.Column1;
       record.Column2 = storeDatabaseRow.Column2;

       records[record.StoreInfoID] = record;
   }
   ```
3. If your database records are lightweight and disconnected, why not just refer to the entire database record from the dictionary?

   ```
   var records = new Dictionary<int, StoreInfo>();

   foreach (var storeDatabaseRow in storeList)
       records[storeDatabaseRow.store_info_id] = storeDatabaseRow;
   ```

   or, using LINQ:

   ```
   var records = storeList.ToDictionary(keySelector: row => row.store_info_id);
   ```